# RewriteEngine htaccess 404 Not found Failed to load resource but its working

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I put this code to my .htaccess
but whenever i visit website.com/link2?v=12345
it gives me an error of **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) website.com/link2?v=12345**. But the page is fine and working it loaded the resources fines, only thing is that the chrome gives me an error like this and I don't know why.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link2$ /link1/index.php?v=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably should be this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^link2$ /link1/index.php$1 [QSA,L]
```